# Android Studio, how to retrieve data from Sqlite database and display it into textview?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I created an SQLite Database in my app, and I insert the data into it. And now I want to retrieve data from it but I want just insert one data and retrieve it then display it into a TextView.

```
public class Db_sqlit extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String TABLE_NAME = "BallsTable";

    public final static String name = "db_data";

    public Db_sqlit(Context context) {
        super(context, name, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ball TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String balls){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

      contentValues.put("ball",balls);

      long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
      if(result == -1){
          return false;
      }
      else
          return true;
    }

    public void list_balls(TextView textView) {

        Cursor res = this.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select ball from "+TABLE_NAME+"",null);
        textView.setText("");
        while (res.moveToNext()){
            textView.append(res.getString(1));
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: i dont have a problem but i dont know how to retrieve data from Sqlite database, i want to retrieve just one data from Sqlite database and display it into Textview can u help me?

Comment: Ok but you just posted your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class,  where do you call `insertData` from?

Comment: i want to insert data into SQliteIpenHelper and then call a method to get this data . like i want to set the default data in the SQliteOpenHelper can i do it?

Comment: I understood the question.. yes you can

Comment: so how can i do it ? thank u

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example of how I achieved this.

In this example I will `store`, `retrieve`, `update` and `delete` a students name and age.

---

First create a class, I called mine

**DBManager.java**

```
public class DBManager {
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private SQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public DBManager(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        this.dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this.context);
        this.database = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert(String name, String desc) {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper.NAME, name);
        contentValue.put(SQLiteHelper.AGE, desc);
        this.database.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, null, contentValue);
    }


    public Cursor fetch() {
        Cursor cursor = this.database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, new String[]{SQLiteHelper._ID, SQLiteHelper.NAME, SQLiteHelper.AGE}, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int update(long _id, String name, String desc) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.AGE, desc);
        return this.database.update(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, contentValues, "_id = " + _id, null);
    }

    public void delete(long _id) {
        this.database.delete(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME_STUDENT, "_id=" + _id, null);
    }
}
```

Then create a `SQLiteOpenHelper` I called mine

**SQLiteHelper.java**

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String AGE = "age";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = " create table STUDENTS ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL , age TEXT );";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "STUDENTS.DB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_STUDENT = "STUDENTS";
    public static final String _ID = "_id";

    public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STUDENTS");
        onCreate(db);
    }   
}
```

---

**TO ADD:**

In this example I take the text from `EditText` and when the button is clicked I check if the `EditText` is empty or not. If it is not empty and the student doesn't already exist I insert the students name and age into the database. I display a `Toast`, letting the user know of the status:

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (edtName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide your students name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            try {
                if (edtAge.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                    String name = edtName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String age = edtAge.getText().toString().trim();
                    String query = "Select * From STUDENTS where name = '"+name+"'";
                    if(dbManager.fetch().getCount()>0){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        dbManager.insert(name, age);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                           
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please provide student age!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                           
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }  
});
```

---

**TO UPDATE:**
Here I take the Text in `EditText` and update the student when the button is clicked. You can also place the following in a `try/catch` to make sure it is updated successfully.

```
btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String name = nameText.getText().toString();
        String age = ageText.getText().toString();
        dbManager.update(_id, name, age);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

---

**TO DELETE:**

```
dbManager.delete(_id);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

---

**TO GET:**

Here I get the name of the student and display it in a `TextView`

```
DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(getActivity());
dbManager.open();

Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
cursor.moveToFirst();
final TextView studentName = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nameOfStudent);
studentName.settext(cursor.getString(0));
```

Comment: thank u so much for your effort but i dont want to get the data from textview and insert it to data. i want to retrieve data from db_sqlit and when i retrieve it then i will set it in a textview

Comment: yes ,  and i want to retrieve it but i insert just one string and i want to retrieve it not retrieve all data and when i retrieve it i want to set it into textview

Comment: i saw your update but sorry i dont know how to write it . i dont find method openDatabase() and the object myDatabaseHelper please can u do another way?

Comment: I will be updating how I did it then you can decide how you want to do it

Comment: hello @HB. can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927770/fetch-text-from-sq-lite too?

Answer (score 0):

**Then I have implement the code in main java class where I want to show using cursor.moveToNext()**

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor result = databaseSQLite2.searchData(searchET.getText().toString());
            while (result.moveToNext()){
                searchresultTV.setText(result.getString(2));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

**For fetching data from sqlite I have done this method in DatabaseHelper class**

```
public Cursor searchData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //String qry = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID="+id;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID="+id,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: This is okay but problem comes next

Comment: When you provide an answer, do not just provide a block of code. Please elaborate on what the code does and why it will solve the issue.