# How to retrieve data from SQLite on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am working on a project that uses Ionic 1 and AngularJS. I have successfully stored data in SQLite. On the simulator of the Ionic (using `ionic serve --lab`) the data is displayed (`console.log()`) as follows:

```
SQLResultSetRowList {0: {…}, length: 1}
0: { // data }
length: 1
```

So I can get the data easily from accessing the object in the result array. However, on real mobile device (I am testing on Android), the data is displayed like this.

[image]

The problem is in here. I want to access the `rows` inside the `Closure` of that `<function scope>` that is inside the `item: function`, which I really don't know how it is generated (and I mean all of these) because the only result I want is as how I got just like in the simulator.

This is how I inserted the data.

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO token (token) VALUES (?)", [myData]).then(function (res) {
                callback();
            }, function (error) {
                ErrorHandler.handle(error);
            });
```

This is how I query the data.

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM token").then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }, function (error) {
                ErrorHandler.handle(error);
            });
```

Anyone has an idea to solve this?

Any way is acceptable.

Comment: Here are some useful answers for your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876568/android-studio-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-and-display-it-into-textview

Comment: @Thamidunaveen Codes in the link you mentioned is written in Java. I don't know which information in there is useful to me in this case. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have found the solution to solve this problem myself from [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/441).

I need to use it like this.

```
if (res.rows.length > 0){
                    if (window.cordova) {
                        // Mobile Device
                        console.log(JSON.parse(res.rows.item(0)));
                    } else {
                        // Web
                        console.log(JSON.parse(res.rows[0]));
                    }
}
```