# I want to retrieve password from the database from the corresponding username but i am unable to do it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i basically want to use the query select password from Login_table where `username ='this will be given by the user';`

```
Cursor res =db.rawQuery("select password from Login_table where username ='"+x+"'",null);
```

i guess this is right but still getting a problem

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 2

```
public void checkData(){
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String user_name=usname.getText().toString();
                Cursor res =mydb.getData(user_name);
                if(res.getCount()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                String check=res.getString(2);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(check),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String pass_Word=pass.getText().toString();

                if(pass_Word.compareTo(check)==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are Loged IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeTextenter code here(MainActivity.this,"You are Not Loged IN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

i just want to retrieve the password and check with the users input`enter code here`

Comment: Have a look at my answer provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884971/5550161

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the index out of bounds is that you are trying to read data from the position that is **BEFORE THE FIRST ROW** i.e. -1. You have to **move** to a row to read data from the row.

So before the line `String check=res.getString(2);` you need to move to a row, probably using the Cursor's **moveToFirst** method (although according to the message there are 2 rows returned, which is an issue you would probably want to address as it would appear that there are two rows for the same user and perhaps 2 different passwords).

As the **moveToFirst** method returns a boolean, **true** if the move could be made, else false, then there is no need to check to see if there are any rows as if there are not then **moveToFirst** will return false.

Although probably not currently an issue. You should also always close a Cursor when done with it.

As such you may wish to try using :-

```
public void checkData(){
    final DBAssetHelper mydb;
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String user_name=usname.getText().toString();
            Cursor res =mydb.getData(user_name);
            if (res.moveToFirst()) { //<<<<<<<<<< try to move to a row
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            } else {
                if (res.getString(2).equals(pass.getText().toString)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are Loged IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You are Not Loged IN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            res.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< Close the Cursor
        }
    });
}
```