# How to retrieve Data from sqlite by user input

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-sqlite

Currently I’m developing a small  app. I want to retrieve data from sqlite by user input. I have two table Gender_Group and Foods.  I want to retrieve data from these tables by user input.
 For example app will ask  to user to put input field  e.g. Age, Gender  to show data according to these fields. When user will insert input , app will show the data according to input field. Can someone help me , how can I write code to implement above functionality.

```
public class DBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private  static  final String dname= "NutritionDatabase";
    private static final int version =4;


    public DBClass(Context context){

        super(context, dname,null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            String gender_cat = "CREATE TABLE  gender_group" +
                    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    "name VARCHAR )";
            db.execSQL(gender_cat);

            String foodtbl = "CREATE TABLE Foods" +
                    "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "age VARCHAR ," +
                    "gender_cat INTEGER," +
                    "Food VARCHAR," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY (gender_cat) REFERENCES gender_group(id))";
            db.execSQL(foodtbl);

 InsertGenderCat(1,"Men",db);
            InsertGenderCat(2,"Women",db);
            InsertGenderCat(3,"Toddlers",db);
            InsertGenderCat(4,"Olders",db);     

        insertFoods("12",2,"Calories Required \n 45 to 55 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 1 gram per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches. \n 1 bagel or muffin.\n 2 slices bread.\n 1/2 cup cooked cereal, pasta, potatoes, or rice. \n\n Fruits:\n 1/2 cup canned fruit or fruit juice. \n 1 piece fresh fruit, such as an apple, orange, peach, or pear. \n\n 15 to 20 grapes.\n\n Meat or Meat Substitutes:\n 1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese. \n 3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes. \n 1 egg.\n 2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n\n  Milk or Yogurt\n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable. \n 2 cups salad greens. \n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\nSweets and Desserts .",db);
        insertFoods("13",2,"Calories Required \n 45 to 55 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 1 gram per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches. \n 1 bagel or muffin.\n 2 slices bread.\n 1/2 cup cooked cereal, pasta, potatoes, or rice. \n\n Fruits:\n 1/2 cup canned fruit or fruit juice. \n 1 piece fresh fruit, such as an apple, orange, peach, or pear. \n\n 15 to 20 grapes.\n\n Meat or Meat Substitutes:\n 1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese. \n 3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes. \n 1 egg.\n 2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n\n  Milk or Yogurt\n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable. \n 2 cups salad greens. \n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\nSweets and Desserts .",db);
        insertFoods("14",2,"Calories Required \n 45 to 55 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 1 gram per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches. \n 1 bagel or muffin.\n 2 slices bread.\n 1/2 cup cooked cereal, pasta, potatoes, or rice. \n\n Fruits:\n 1/2 cup canned fruit or fruit juice. \n 1 piece fresh fruit, such as an apple, orange, peach, or pear. \n\n 15 to 20 grapes.\n\n Meat or Meat Substitutes:\n 1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese. \n 3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes. \n 1 egg.\n 2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n\n  Milk or Yogurt\n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable. \n 2 cups salad greens. \n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\nSweets and Desserts .",db);
        insertFoods("15",2,"Total Calories Required \n 40 to 45 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 0.9 grams per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches::1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese.3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes.\n 1 egg.2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n  Milk or Yogurt \n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable.\n 2 cups salad greens.\n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\n Sweets and Desserts .",db);
        insertFoods("16",2,"Total Calories Required \n 40 to 45 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 0.9 grams per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches::1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese.3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes.\n 1 egg.2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n  Milk or Yogurt \n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable.\n 2 cups salad greens.\n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\n Sweets and Desserts .",db);
        insertFoods("17",2,"Total Calories Required \n 40 to 45 calories per kg.\n\n Protein \n 0.9 grams per kg. \n\n Breads or Starches::1/2 cup cottage or ricotta cheese.3/4 to 1 cup cooked dried beans or legumes.\n 1 egg.2 to 3 ounces meat, fish, or poultry.\n  Milk or Yogurt \n 1 cup  milk or yogurt.\n\n Vegetables:\n 1/2 cup cooked or 1 cup raw vegetable.\n 2 cups salad greens.\n\n Fats\n 6 almonds or 10 peanuts.\n 2 Tbsps cream cheese, avocado, or low calorie salad dressing.\n\n Sweets and Desserts .",db);


            }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

     private void  InsertGenderCat(Integer id, String group, SQLiteDatabase db){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("id",id);
        values.put("name",group);
        db.insert("gender_group", null,values);
    }
    private  void  insertFoods(String age,Integer cat, String food,  SQLiteDatabase db){
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

     values.put("age",age);
        values.put("gender_cat",cat);
     values.put("Food",food);
        db.insert("Foods", null,values);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            String genderTbl  ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gender_categories";
        db.execSQL(genderTbl);
        String foodsTbl  ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Foods";
        db.execSQL(foodsTbl);
}
}
```

Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBmr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fill The Field  to Find Food"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_gender_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="18dp"
            android:text="Gender Group :"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_gender_group"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_genderGroup_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="18dp"
            android:text="Enter Age :"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_genderGroup_age"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_food"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Click to show Foods"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you created a layout which has `editText`?

Comment: Yes . I created layout

Comment: I posted layout file code please check it.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876568/android-studio-retrieve-data-from-sqlite-database-and-display-it-into-textview

Comment: @JohnJoe  i checked but it is not helpful for me.. please can you share source which similar to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the two `editText` value when the button is clicked. Then pass the two values to `readEntry` function, which is inside **DBManager** class.

```
btnFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = dbManager.open().readEntry(genderGroup.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString());
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String value = cursor.getString(0);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

            }
        });
```

Inside **DBManager** class, write the query in `readEntry` functionWe can use `Left-join` query to join two tables.

```
public class DBManager {

    private DBClass dbhelper;
    private Context context;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DBManager(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        dbhelper = new DBClass(context);
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbhelper.close();
    }


    public Cursor readEntry(String genderGroup, String age) {
        return database.rawQuery("SELECT i.food FROM foods i LEFT JOIN gender_group w ON i.gender_cat = w.id  WHERE w.name = ? AND i.age = ?", new String[]{genderGroup, age}, null);
    } 
}
```

The output will be displayed as `Toast`.

You can get full project here : https://github.com/tony123S/ProjectApp

Comment: Thank you so much.. Please, can you share complete code?

Comment: When the show food button is clicked, pass the name and age to readEntry function.

Comment: do you know how to get editText value when button is clicked?

Comment: please upload your project to github. I will help if I'm free.

Comment: I uploaded please check it .                                      https://github.com/sufyan310/ProjectApp

Comment: I am waiting ur response .

Comment: app will ask to user enter age and gender group (male, female or child etc), after entering these inputs, when user will click on show food button, app will fetch the data from database according to these field and show .

Comment: Thank you so much @John Joe , amazing it is working. But how can i display this data in text-view ?

Comment: add textView inside your layout.Make it visible after `cursor.moveToFirst()`.